# Share big complex Python object between Gunicorn workers

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, python-multiprocessing

I am using Gunicorn with the MeinheldWorker worker class to serve a web app. I use ~20 workers.

The problem is that I have a big complex Python object that I need to share between the multiple processes.

I tried Gunicorn's **preload** option, since this is a read-only object as far as the workers are concerned, but I also want the object to be updated every once in a while, so that doesn't work for me.

Is this something that can be done with Gunicorn or I should implement a custom solution using [multiprocessing.managers](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) or [Memory-mapped](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html) file objects?